# AngularJS Toaster does not show on callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I'm using AngularJS Toaster to show toast messages. But i can't seem to get it working with a result from a callback, and i REALLY don't know why.

I've created a service for Toaster:

```
service.factory('$toasterservice', ['toaster',
    function (toaster) {
        return {
            'show': function (type, title, text) {
                return toaster.pop({
                    type: type,
                    title: title,
                    body: text,
                    showCloseButton: false
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

This piece of code is in my controller:

```
$scope.submit = function (db) {

            var params = {
                username: db.credentials.username,
                password: db.credentials.password,
                database: db.name,
                hostname: db.host,
                port: db.port
            };

            $dbservice.testConnection(params, function (response) {
                if (response.error)
                {
                    console.log(response.error)
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('correct!');                    
                }
            });

        };
```

whenever i put this line of code:

```
$toasterservice.show('error', 'TITLE', 'BODY');
```

within controller level scope, it works perfectly fine.

When ever i try to use it in:

```
$dbservice.testConnection(params, function (response) {
             //HERE $toasterservice.show('error', 'TITLE', 'BODY');
            });
```

it doesn't work, how can i solve this? i can't seem to understand why this is happening.

$dbservice :

```
service.factory('$dbservice', ['$constants',
function ($constants) {

    return {
        'testConnection': function (params, callback) {               

            $.ajax({
                url: $constants.URL_TEST_CONNECTION,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                data: params,
                success: callback,
                error: callback
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Do you see any result? Can you put the the call to the toaster service inside the 'correct' part of the dbservice response? Is there an ajax error occurring? What does the network inspector show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is using `$.ajax` and you should switch to using `$http`.

Any events that occur outside of angular core that change the scope need to notify angular so it can run digest in view.

You can call `$scope.$apply()` in the callback of your `$.ajax` to run digest